# Is it grammatically correct to say 'to play computer'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wonder whether one can actually say 'I play computer every once in a while' instead of 'I play computer games every once in a while'. I haven't come across the former phrase in any written context and I doubt whether it can be considered grammatically correct.

Comment: You may play computer games, or play games (or music or videos) on your computer, but to play a/the computer means either to play a game with the computer as your opponent, like chess players, or to perform a work using the computer as your instrument, like Wendy Williams.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, but "play computer" is also totally valid. Even if the computer is not your opponent.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Really? I'll consult my expert on Millennial idiom when he gets home from work and confirm this.

Comment: "Play computer" is incomprehensible to me.  (Well, I could make a guess if I had enough context, but it's not something people say as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: To me it sounds like either mistaken/child grammar, or a phrase meaning "to pretend to be a computer". But that just shows what I know, doesn't it.

Comment: When I was in school, way back awhile, we students would *"play computer"* when we would step through our code. This for higher level languages (e.g. fortran, pascal, etc.) and for assembler and for microcode. Especially for microcode, we students would act like we are the CPU, and for each instruction and for each clock cycle, indicate what goes on what busses and what gates get opened and closed, etc. Yup, we played computer a lot in those days (including the days when a program was punched cards), such as when a program was diodes and resistors on a board.

Comment: @ F.E.: Yes, that is just what I'd think if I heard someone say "play computer": that they were pretending to be one, like when you "play horse" for kids.

Comment: I would say __play **on** computer__

Comment: @jamesqf is the word chunk 'to play horse' used without any article whatsoever in the sense mentioned above? I've never come across it or just didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it gramatically correct? I'm not sure. A computer is not something that can be played. You can play *on* the computer, and you can play a *computer game*.

Is it acceptable to say? **Absolutely!** I say "playing computer" all the time. Actually, I probably say this more often than "playing computer games". Everybody will understand your meaning, and I doubt that anybody would think it sounds strange.

Now, StoneyB has a good point, if you say "playing **the** computer" (or even "a computer") it implies you are playing **against** a computer. This would sound a little bit strange unless someone is asking **who** you are playing against.

> What are you doing?
>
> "I'm playing computer." *OR* "I'm playing on the computer." *OR* "I'm playing computer games."

These all sound perfectly fine.

> Who are you playing against?
>
> "I'm playing the computer." *OR* "I'm playing against the computer."

Both of these also sound fine.

Comment: Perhaps this wording is "perfectly fine" within the gaming community. It sounds off to me, though. Still, I'm glad you explained this in your answer. LSNED.

Comment: LSNED? What does that mean?

Comment: @ J.R. Well, I do not consider myself part of "The Gaming Community". I am actually shocked, I have always said this, and everyone I know frequently says this. It was not until today that I learned this isn't actually common. However, I'll take your word for it, since I seem to be in the minority here.

Comment: It's ***Learn Something New Every Day!***

Comment: @DJMcMayhem From my son, 25, who *is* a member of TGC: he has not encountered this, and if he did would take it to be mockery of non-native (probably Asian English) usage. However, "play *vidja* or *vidya*" is common in internet posts and messaging to mean "play video games". Apparently you and your circle have established a local dialect usage; perhaps it will catch on!

Comment: @StoneyB Just out of curiosity, does it sound correct if someone says, for example,  "Playing Xbox"?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I'll ask my House Expert. To me 'play computer', 'play Xbox' have the same sort of ring as 'play baseball diamond', 'play tennis court'.

Comment: @Yukatan Actually, I recommend you do not accept this answer. Apparently I am one of the few people that says "Play Computer". According to StoneyB, and Maulik V, and F.E. and snailboat, and basically everybody in this thread, it sounds wrong to most native speakers.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem sounds correct if Xbox is a *musical instrument!* :)

Comment: @MaulikV: Not at all! We don't say "play flute" or "play piano". This is the same mistake involving the definite article as in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either you ***play something*** or ***play with/against something***.

The verb 'play' is taking a direct object in first case, which is your concern. **Purely** in the context of 'gaming', the **direct object** is some game in almost all the cases.

Said that...

> Play football/cricket/rugby/chess and so on - All are **games**.

But...

> Play computer -seems no standard English *(at least to me)*.

**Even if it is grammatical**, it's ***ambiguous*** for sure.

However, you may ...

> "... play with/against the computer".

Comment: It's grammatically correct to perform a verb on a noun. I resent being told I'm playing computers and also that I'm "playing" Lego. (Not least of all because one doesn't play Lego. Children might play "with" Lego, but not me. I "construct" with Lego.

Comment: In standard English we do **not** say "play with/against computer". It must be "play with/against **the** computer".

Comment: @user21820 true! Corrected!

Comment: @MaulikV: Thanks! I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We say "play [*game/sport*]" such as in:

> play soccer/chess/go (the game's name makes it definite and hence no definite article is used)

And we say "play the [*instrument*]" such as in:

> play the piano

And we say "play with [*the tool* / *tools*]" such as in:

> play with the computer / play with computers

And we say "play against [*the opponent* / *opponents*]" such as in:

> play against the computer

And we say "play the [*role*]" such as in:

> play the fool/king/thief/computer (the last one includes pretending to be a computer)

---

Also, note that Standard English requires the use of the definite article in "**the** computer", and omitting it is ungrammatical. This is because "the computer" refers to a generic computer, not a specific one (which "a computer" would refer to), and all count nouns need a determiner such as the definite or indefinite article.